# Using a central PHP includes file

Tags: php

What is the correct way to use a PHP file for e.g. `includes.php` for different things and then pull those sections in to other PHP files?

For e.g. in `includes.php`:

`#footer <p>&copy; Copyright 2014 | <a href="legal.php">Legal</a></p>`

And then in `index.php`:

`<?php include("includes.php#footer"); ?>`

Is this sort of thing possible?

Comment: You could create a function in `includes.php` which you refer to from `index.php`

Comment: There is no "correct" pattern, but I personally would avoid going about it as you've described. I would isolate each partial into its own file and explicitly include them. For example: `include("partials/header.php");`, `include("partials/footer.php");`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store an array in your `includes.php`:

```
return array(
    'footer' => '<p>&copy; Copyright 2014 | <a href="legal.php">Legal</a></p>',
);
```

And than in `index.php` pull it in such a way:

```
$templates = include("includes.php#footer");
$footer = $templates["footer"];
```